Errors building flutter app The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0
I am trying to build my flutter app , actually it is being built , I am just wondering why are these errors occuring :
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\mehdidx\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\cloud_firestore-4.16.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
e: C:/Users/mehdidx/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/08d55680ad2953abe77528c3a5186df7/transformed/jetified-activity-1.8.0/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/activity_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of
its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/mehdidx/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0153c5737100b82145406b86e4ef994e/transformed/lifecycle-livedata-core-2.6.2/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-livedata-core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/mehdidx/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/d12f1d469fe801b5b8082d7a451d6302/transformed/lifecycle-viewmodel-2.6.2/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-viewmodel_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/mehdidx/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.lifecycle/lifecycle-common/2.6.2/10f354fdb64868baecd67128560c5a0d6312c495/lifecycle-common-2.6.2.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/mehdidx/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/f530314e540fd09a3cbc96e5c6d4e417/transformed/lifecycle-runtime-2.6.2/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-runtime_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/mehdidx/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/545777a4083296e1c6ca842ea6fe72ce/transformed/jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate-2.6.2/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/mehdidx/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/f94a94e54ee142344f59d32478bb5e64/transformed/jetified-core-ktx-1.13.0-rc01/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/core-ktx_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/mehdidx/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/20cb6c56a01460f0a0e884fcc3631f59/transformed/core-1.13.0-rc01/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/mehdidx/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/526bb5512d8d3f2d15bcce29fe0c92ba/transformed/jetified-savedstate-1.2.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/savedstate_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/mehdidx/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm/1.7.3/2b09627576f0989a436a00a4a54b55fa5026fb86/kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.7.3.jar!/META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-core.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/mehdidx/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-android/1.7.3/38d9cad3a0b03a10453b56577984bdeb48edeed5/kotlinx-coroutines-android-1.7.3.jar!/META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-android.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/mehdidx/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.22/636bf8b320e7627482771bbac9ed7246773c02bd/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/mehdidx/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.22/636bf8b320e7627482771bbac9ed7246773c02bd/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/mehdidx/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.22/636bf8b320e7627482771bbac9ed7246773c02bd/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/mehdidx/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.8.22/1a8e3601703ae14bb58757ea6b2d8e8e5935a586/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
